# PHP Regex for get line between # and #

Tags: php, regex

I'm kind of stuck with a very simple regex. I've already tried a lot of thing but without result so I'll go with the simple :

I want to get a multiline result (for replace it later but I have already wrote this part and it works good) which supposed to be between '#' char. here the sample file :

```
# Zulu 9.8.9.8
add method 9.8.9.8 {ssh} {telnet}
add password 9.8.9.8 {jouejoue}
add user 9.8.9.8 {Zekrom}
# Zulu 1.1.1.1
add method 1.1.1.1 {ssh} {telnet}
add password 1.1.1.1 {mypassword}
add user 1.1.1.1 {adminstyle}
# Zulu 2.2.2.2
add method 2.2.2.2 {ssh} {telnet}
add password 2.2.2.2 {diffpassword}
add user 2.2.2.2 {pixyokadi}
```

I used 's' option like '/regex/s' so "\n" will be count in '.' char. I wanted to use [^#] but it cancelled the 's' option. I don't know why but when using this one :

```
/#.*#/s
```

It takes the 2 first paragraph ignoring the '#' at line '# Zulu 1.1.1.1' and I don't understand why. I've tried to use capture-parenthesis too without success. I used to search the IP with a regex but since I can't even get the paragraph I wanted, I used a more simple one. Could someone explain this to me ?

https://regex101.com/r/tI4hQ7/2

Thanks for reading.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Exactly what hsz propose me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with following regex:

```
/#[^#]*/g
```

`g` modifier does the global search.

Also with `[^#]*` you will not capture next occurences of `#` - just everything else than `#` sign.

Example:

https://regex101.com/r/tI4hQ7/5

Comment: Since the question specifies (or perhaps just happens to say, who knows?) _between #_, you could limit down the result by doing `/(?<=#)[^#]*/g`, excluding the octothorpe-hash-pound signs at both ends.

Comment: That's right Janus, I wanted to select the all and would have add the capture parenthesis to output extra #. Thx for your answers.

Comment: `preg_match_all` does the global search :p `\g` modifier does nothing